# How to emerge a window in a parent windows form?

Tags: c#, matlab

I'm developing some app that runs a command and open a MATLAB window to plot a graph, I need to catch this new window and show it inside the parent windows form which initiate that. it's actually that MATLAB that opens this new window, but is there anyway to catch it and put it in my window? thanks

Comment: Are you trying to treat the Window like a `MDI Child Form`? I'm not entirely sure what you mean by *catch it and put it in my window*.  What type of Window?

Comment: I guess the application you are developing is using windows forms right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want something like an Iframe object where you load the new content into that container yet it feels that it is part of the same application. Unfortunately out of the box you cannot to it, unless the MathLab object provides some ActiveX object you can use from the Application itself. What you can do thought is simulate that the external exe is part of the application using the Win32 API. See if this helps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace CarPC
{
public partial class MainForm
{
#region Methods/Consts for Embedding a Window
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowThreadProcessId", SetLastError = true,
         CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true,
         CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern long GetWindowThreadProcessId(long hWnd, long lpdwProcessId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern long SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLongA", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern long GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern long SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, long hWndInsertAfter, long x, long y, long cx, long cy, long wFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    private const int SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x200;
    private const int SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x8;
    private const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x4;
    private const int SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040;
    private const int WS_EX_MDICHILD = 0x40;
    private const int SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x20;
    private const int SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x10;
    private const int SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000;
    private const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x2;
    private const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x1;
    private const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
    private const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
    private const int WM_CLOSE = 0x10;
    private const int WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
    private const int WS_MAXIMIZE = 0x01000000;
    #endregion
    #region Variables
    private Panel gpsPanel;
    private IntPtr gpsHandle;
    private Process gpsProcess = null;
    private ProcessStartInfo gpsPSI = new ProcessStartInfo();
    #endregion
    private void SetupGPSPanel()
    {
        //Panel to Contain Controls
        this.gpsPanel = new Panel();
        this.gpsPanel.Location = new Point(this.LeftBarRight, this.TopBarBottom);
        this.gpsPanel.Size = new Size(this.Size.Width - this.LeftBarRight, this.Size.Height - this.TopBarBottom);
        this.gpsPanel.Visible = false;

        gpsPSI.FileName = "notepad.exe";
        gpsPSI.Arguments = "";
        gpsPSI.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
        gpsProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(gpsPSI);
        gpsProcess.WaitForInputIdle();
        gpsHandle = gpsProcess.MainWindowHandle;
        SetParent(gpsHandle, this.gpsPanel.Handle);
        SetWindowLong(gpsHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE + WS_MAXIMIZE);
        MoveWindow(gpsHandle, 0,0, this.gpsPanel.Width, this.gpsPanel.Height, true);

        this.Controls.Add(gpsPanel);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Hosting EXE Applications in a WinForm project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply build your *Matlab Project* as a *.Net* or *COM* Object-Component.  So you'll build and package the component like this:

- Select the type of component to build (.Net or COM)
- Add Matlab code files and MEX-Files to be accessed as public methods of your component.
- Specify a .Net interface defining the generated type-safe API.
- Set properties for building and packaging.
- Build, then test your component to ensure it is functional.
- Package the component and the MCR for programmers or end users.

Once you've done those above steps, you'll be able to access the *Matlab Component* as any other object component from Visual Studio.  You can then pass objects natively from *Matlab and .Net* without any issues.

As the data has been converted; so it will interact like any other component.

Then you can simply interact or interface by dragging your component on a *Windows Form* and treat it like any other `MDI`.

```
MatlabComponentFrm m = new MatlabComponentFrm();
m.MdiParent = this;
m.Show();
```

Very simple example.  That would be the easiest in my opinion.  Otherwise you can import, or host executable.  You have quite a few ways to accomplish this.  Hopefully that helps.